# SQL sum by weekly buckets

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is similar to some other questions on here however not close enough that I have all the info to do it myself. I want to pivot a date range with ability to limit by year. I'm not sure how they want to limit the data at the moment, maybe a year previous to a year forward for now.

I want the start day of the week to be Monday and end to be Sunday.  Any quantities to fall between these days to be summed for the week per reftype with the date displaying as that starting Monday.

I have data below.

```
+---------+---------+------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+
| Itemid  | RefType | name             | OriginalReqDate         | Qty                    |
+---------+---------+------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+
| B406227 | 8       | Purchase order   | 2016-03-04 00:00:00.000 | 2346.0000000000000000  |
+---------+---------+------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+
| B406227 | 12      | Production order | 2016-03-04 00:00:00.000 | -1295.4000000000000000 |
+---------+---------+------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+
| B406227 | 12      | Production order | 2016-03-07 00:00:00.000 | -3651.6000000000000000 |
+---------+---------+------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+
| B406227 | 8       | Purchase order   | 2016-03-11 00:00:00.000 | 4692.0000000000000000  |
+---------+---------+------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+
| B406227 | 12      | Production order | 2016-03-14 00:00:00.000 | -1397.4000000000000000 |
+---------+---------+------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+
| B406227 | 12      | Production order | 2016-03-21 00:00:00.000 | -958.8000000000000000  |
+---------+---------+------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+
| B406227 | 45      | Formula line     | 2016-03-28 00:00:00.000 | -696.1700000000000000  |
+---------+---------+------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+
| B406227 | 45      | Formula line     | 2016-04-03 00:00:00.000 | -527.5500000000000000  |
+---------+---------+------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+
| B406227 | 8       | Purchase order   | 2016-04-07 00:00:00.000 | 7038.0000000000000000  |
+---------+---------+------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+
| B406227 | 45      | Formula line     | 2016-04-07 00:00:00.000 | -1186.5500000000000000 |
+---------+---------+------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+
```

I would like output as

```
+---------+---------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| ItemId  | RefType | Name                   | 2016-03-04             | 2016-03-11             | 2016-03-18             | 2016-03-25            | 2016-04-01            |
+---------+---------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| B406227 | 1       | On-hand                | 470.7600000000000000   | NULL                   | NULL                   | NULL                  | NULL                  |
+---------+---------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| B406227 | 8       | Purchase order         | 2346.0000000000000000  | 4692.0000000000000000  | NULL                   | NULL                  | NULL                  |
+---------+---------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| B406227 | 12      | Production order       | -1295.4000000000000000 | -3651.6000000000000000 | -1397.4000000000000000 | -958.8000000000000000 | NULL                  |
+---------+---------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| B406227 | 33      | Planned purchase order | NULL                   | NULL                   | NULL                   | NULL                  | NULL                  |
+---------+---------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| B406227 | 45      | Formula line           | NULL                   | NULL                   | NULL                   | NULL                  | -696.1700000000000000 |
+---------+---------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| B406227 | 99      | Total for B406227      | 1992.1200000000000000  | 2561.7600000000000000  | 1164.3600000000000000  | 205.5600000000000000  | -490.6100000000000000 |
+---------+---------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

This is my attempt:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tt', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE tt;

DECLARE @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT  @Columns = COALESCE(@Columns + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(ReqDate)
FROM    ( SELECT DISTINCT
                    CAST(ReqDate AS DATE) AS ReqDate
          FROM      SourceTable
        ) AS A
ORDER BY A.ReqDate;

SET @SQL = 'WITH PivotData AS (SELECT DataAreaId, ItemId, RefType, Name, ReqDate, Qty
FROM SourceTable) 
SELECT DataAreaId, ItemId, RefType, Name ' + @Columns + ' 
INTO tt
FROM PivotData

PIVOT
(SUM(Qty)
FOR ReqDate IN (' + @Columns + ')

) AS PivotResult ORDER BY DataAreaId, ItemId, RefType';

EXEC (@SQL);

IF OBJECT_ID('adhoc.V_tt', 'V') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW adhoc.V_tt;

    GO

CREATE VIEW adhoc.V_tt
AS
    ( SELECT    *
      FROM      tt 
    );
```

Comment: Use pivoting query

Comment: hi can you help me get a query together?

Comment: Put your sample data and your query what you tried

Comment: You could use the PIVOT operator in your query, however in my opinion it is not the best of the option...(you have to provide the values for each column in the output...)

how will you render the data? in a report? in excel? almost any kind of reporting tool has the ability to pivot data, so you could pass the query to a Pivot Table in Excel without worrying about pivoting in SQL....

Comment: this will be viewed in a SQL view off of a table.  As it is dynamic it will need to be dropped and created everytime.  I will worry about that, I just need to get a query to output the results as above.

Comment: @jhowe, All your columns are Fridays? What is your actual week?

Comment: @jhowe I just edited my answer and included dynamic SQL to create the correct column-captions...

Comment: (General note: I have edited in material from the question author that _may_ have been a solution attempt best presented in the question, but some comments indicate that it was intended as a final solution, even though it does not correspond to the question. I have reported the answer to the Review Queue but I suspect they have decided not to delete. If anyone wishes to revert my last update here, please go ahead. I have pinged the question author but they not yet responded. cc @Shnugo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### EDIT: Dynamic SQL

With this you would get the column headers dynamically pointing on Sundays...
Attention: Depending on your system's culture you might want to have a look on `SET DATEFIRST` and `@@DATEFIRST`...

```
CREATE TABLE #TestTbl(Itemid VARCHAR(100),RefType INT,name VARCHAR(100),OriginalReqDate DATETIME,Qty DECIMAL(8,2));
INSERT INTO #TestTbl VALUES
 ('B406227',8,'Purchase order','2016-03-04T00:00:00.000',2346.0000000000000000)
,('B406227',12,'Production order','2016-03-04T00:00:00.000',-1295.4000000000000000)
,('B406227',12,'Production order','2016-03-07T00:00:00.000',-3651.6000000000000000)
,('B406227',8,'Purchase order','2016-03-11T00:00:00.000',4692.0000000000000000)
,('B406227',12,'Production order','2016-03-14T00:00:00.000',-1397.4000000000000000)
,('B406227',12,'Production order','2016-03-21T00:00:00.000',-958.8000000000000000)
,('B406227',45,'Formula line','2016-03-28T00:00:00.000',-696.1700000000000000)
,('B406227',45,'Formula line','2016-04-03T00:00:00.000',-527.5500000000000000)
,('B406227',8,'Purchase order','2016-04-07T00:00:00.000',7038.0000000000000000)
,('B406227',45,'Formula line','2016-04-07T00:00:00.000',-1186.5500000000000000);

DECLARE @colNames VARCHAR(MAX)=
STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT ',[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,DATEPART(DW,OriginalReqDate) * (-1),OriginalReqDate),120) + ']'
        FROM #TestTbl
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,''
);

DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)=
'
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT tt.Itemid
          ,tt.RefType
          ,tt.name
          ,SUM(Qty) AS SumQty
          ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,DATEPART(DW,OriginalReqDate) * (-1),OriginalReqDate),120) AS ColumName 
    FROM #TestTbl AS tt
    GROUP BY ItemId,RefType,name,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,DATEPART(DW,OriginalReqDate) * (-1),OriginalReqDate),120)
) AS tbl
PIVOT
(
    SUM(SumQty) FOR ColumName IN(' +  @colNames + ')
) AS p
';

EXEC (@cmd);

DROP TABLE #TestTbl;
```

The result:

```
Itemid  RefType name             2016-02-28 2016-03-06  2016-03-13  2016-03-20  2016-03-27  2016-04-03
B406227 8       Purchase order   2346.00    4692.00     NULL        NULL        NULL         7038.00
B406227 12      Production order -1295.40   -3651.60    -1397.40    -958.80     NULL         NULL
B406227 45      Formula line      NULL      NULL        NULL        NULL       -1223.72     -1186.55
```

#### Previous

This is a hard coded approach for the given sample data. If you want your columns to get a caption like `2016-03-04` you might think about dynamic SQL or you create the `columnName` (and the `IN() list`) for the correct output.

```
CREATE TABLE #TestTbl(Itemid VARCHAR(100),RefType INT,name VARCHAR(100),OriginalReqDate DATETIME,Qty DECIMAL(8,2));
INSERT INTO #TestTbl VALUES
 ('B406227',8,'Purchase order','2016-03-04T00:00:00.000',2346.0000000000000000)
,('B406227',12,'Production order','2016-03-04T00:00:00.000',-1295.4000000000000000)
,('B406227',12,'Production order','2016-03-07T00:00:00.000',-3651.6000000000000000)
,('B406227',8,'Purchase order','2016-03-11T00:00:00.000',4692.0000000000000000)
,('B406227',12,'Production order','2016-03-14T00:00:00.000',-1397.4000000000000000)
,('B406227',12,'Production order','2016-03-21T00:00:00.000',-958.8000000000000000)
,('B406227',45,'Formula line','2016-03-28T00:00:00.000',-696.1700000000000000)
,('B406227',45,'Formula line','2016-04-03T00:00:00.000',-527.5500000000000000)
,('B406227',8,'Purchase order','2016-04-07T00:00:00.000',7038.0000000000000000)
,('B406227',45,'Formula line','2016-04-07T00:00:00.000',-1186.5500000000000000);

SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT tt.Itemid
          ,tt.RefType
          ,tt.name
          ,SUM(Qty) AS SumQty
          ,'w' + CAST(DATEPART(WEEK,OriginalReqDate) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS ColumName 
    FROM #TestTbl AS tt
    GROUP BY ItemId,RefType,name,DATEPART(WEEK,OriginalReqDate) 
) AS tbl
PIVOT
(
    SUM(SumQty) FOR ColumName IN(w10,w11,w12,w13,w14,w15)
) AS p

DROP TABLE #TestTbl;
```

The result:

```
Itemid  RefType name              w10       w11        w12      w13     w14     w15
B406227 8       Purchase order    2346.00   4692.00    NULL     NULL    NULL    7038.00
B406227 12      Production order  -1295.40  -3651.60   -1397.40 -958.80 NULL    NULL  
B406227 45      Formula line      NULL      NULL       NULL     NULL  -1223.72 -1186.55
```

Comment: Btw: Your "Total"-Row should be realised in your application. It would be possible (**but ugly**) to write a `UNION SELECT` and call the query twice. Once for the row values and another time with `SUM()` to all columns...

Comment: Hi Shnugo, thanks for that i just CAST reqdate as DATE to give me required column name format... I've also come up with an answer which i will post shortly...

Comment: @jhowe, In the sample you provided there is no `reqdate`. The dates in `OriginalReqDates` are not in a weekly difference. And - as mentioned above - your expected output shows Fridays...

Comment: sorry reqdate is same as originalreqdate... can you explain how the date part is working in your query?

Answer (score -1):

This is my attempt...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tt', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE tt;

DECLARE @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT  @Columns = COALESCE(@Columns + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(ReqDate)
FROM    ( SELECT DISTINCT
                    CAST(ReqDate AS DATE) AS ReqDate
          FROM      SourceTable
        ) AS A
ORDER BY A.ReqDate;

SET @SQL = 'WITH PivotData AS (SELECT DataAreaId, ItemId, RefType, Name, ReqDate, Qty
FROM SourceTable) 
SELECT DataAreaId, ItemId, RefType, Name ' + @Columns + ' 
INTO tt
FROM PivotData

PIVOT
(SUM(Qty)
FOR ReqDate IN (' + @Columns + ')

) AS PivotResult ORDER BY DataAreaId, ItemId, RefType';

EXEC (@SQL);

IF OBJECT_ID('adhoc.V_tt', 'V') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW adhoc.V_tt;

    GO

CREATE VIEW adhoc.V_tt
AS
    ( SELECT    *
      FROM      tt 
    );
```

Comment: This answer is based upon the fact that your source dates have already been modified...

Comment: I would not see this as an answer, as it does not really reflect the sample structure and data you provided in your question. If my answer was the one which brought you to the solution it would be kind to accept it.

Comment: @Shnugo yes I will be marking yours as answer can you please look at my comments at the bottom of post? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, you edited the last comment: The `OriginalReqDate' , is asked for its `DW (Day of week)` (an index from 1 to 7), this is minused and taken away from the date to reach the week's first day.

Comment: @Shnugo hi i had another meeting with the user for this requirement, when you have a moment can we move this discussion to chat? Thanks...

Comment: Yes, but please let us avoit chameleon questions :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106613/discussion-between-shnugo-and-jhowe).

Comment: This looks like an attempt at the question, rather than an answer, and so I have merged it into the question. I will ask the Review Queue to look at it, and see if it can be deleted from the answer space.

Comment: Shnugo's comments suggest it is not an answer either. However your comments under another answer indicate that it was intended to be an answer. Would you clarify? Either way, it could do with some explanation; presently it is "code only" and so may not be very useful from the perspective of understanding what was changed to make it work.